# Animating GIF image throws exception

Tags: delphi, animated-gif, delphi-xe7

I'm trying to animate a GIF image in XE7, but when I set the Animate property to True an exception is raised.

[image]

Here's the .pas

```
unit Unit6;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  GifImg, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm6 = class(TForm)
    Spinner: TImage;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form6: TForm6;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm6.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TGifImage(Spinner.Picture.Graphic).Animate := True;
end;

end.
```

And the .dfm

```
object Form6: TForm6
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  BorderStyle = bsDialog
  Caption = 'GIF Test'
  ClientHeight = 83
  ClientWidth = 115
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Position = poScreenCenter
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Spinner: TImage
    Left = 45
    Top = 13
    Width = 24
    Height = 24
    AutoSize = True
    IncrementalDisplay = True
    ParentShowHint = False
    Picture.Data = {
      0D546478536D617274496D61676547494638396118001800840000FFFFFF0000
      00CECECEFAFAFAE0E0E0B0B0B0E8E8E88E8E8EC8C8C89C9C9CD8D8D8A8A8A8C0
      C0C0F2F2F2767676868686B8B8B8686868000000000000000000000000000000
      00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000021FE1A4372
      6561746564207769746820616A61786C6F61642E696E666F0021FF0B4E455453
      43415045322E30030100000021F90401070000002C00000000180018000008B3
      0001081C48100004080513262440F0C10385100110708050608408031B308C28
      F081838D170712D8C8118283041D1F02D0D8002249001E5B1E1438D2A5430103
      17B4244852E34B010E51725C397267C6050F16701CF932A1D1A150A30A14B020
      4182053887FA24D0A081000856B142EDCAF4A9D4B368053680203622D3850B16
      4030BBB0E8D10524053CD598B1A6DAA75F5BFAE54A902E4D085907131E7A70A7
      80AC129B3A159017324BAD041FA72DD8756840003B}
    ShowHint = True
    Transparent = True
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 13
    Top = 49
    Width = 91
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
end
```

I have the DevExpress controls installed and the Picture property in the properties editor is declared as a `TcxSmartImage`. However, this class descends from TGraphic, so I don't see how this could cause the exception.

Comment: Based on picture dimensions and the amount of data in Picture.Data field I think it is posible that when you added the gif image at design time it was treated as static gif an therefore only first frame was added. Also from where would TGifImage get all necessary data about animation parametrs (number of frames, frame order, frame delays etc.). I seriosly doubt all the needed information can be stored in so small data block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TGifImage(Spinner.Picture.Graphic).Animate := True;
```

The likely explanation is that `Spinner.Picture.Graphic` is not of type `TGifImage`. I suspect that if you use a runtime checked cast then you will discover that is the case.

```
(Spinner.Picture.Graphic as TGifImage).Animate := True;
```

If you decode the hex contained in the `Picture.Data` context that you showed you find this ASCII text:

```
TdxSmartImage
```

This suggests to me that your image control does not contain `TGifImage`.

---

You should as a general rule. avoid using unchecked casts. If you make a mistake and cast to an invalid type then the outcome is unpredictable with an unchecked cast. The best case scenario is that you get a runtime error and at least realise that there is a problem. However, the runtime error is invariably somewhat cryptic. The worst case scenario with an erroneous unchecked cast is that there is no runtime error and the code appears to work.

On the other hand, an invalid type when used with a runtime checked cast will lead to an informative error message.

---

Thanks to @SpeedFreak for the useful comment which refers to this DevExpress support item: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q562011

It seems that the DevExpress components register their own handler for the GIF extension. And that handler does not support animation.

So I guess that the easiest way to resolve this is to load the GIF image at runtime, from a resource, and this avoid relying on all the design time magic that associates image extensions with graphic components.

Comment: You're correct David. I actually used (Spinner.Picture.Graphic as TGifImage) first, but got the runtime error you mention. I think I'll contact DevExpress and see what they say.

Comment: It seems likely that you'll find a `TdxSmartImageGIF89a` in there!

Comment: Yes, you'd think so, but as far as I can tell, TdxSmartImageGIF89a is not declared anywhere in the DevExpress source. I assume that the class name is generated when the GIF data is streamed, but it was never intended for the actual class type to be used.

Comment: You can find out what type it is with `Spinner.Picture.Graphic.ClassName`. In any case, I think we've got to the bottom of the question you asked.

Comment: Thanks. I'll update the answer when I get a response from DevExpress

Comment: If you examine the hex data you'll notice that the first byte is `0D`. That value specifies the length of the class name string that follows. I.e. the class name is `TdxSmartImage`. The `GIF89a` string following that is the GIF signature that appears at the start of a GIF file. The signature value can be either `GIF87a` or `GIF89a`. Wrt. the use of `TdxSmartImage` there are multiple reports at DevExpress about this problem. So far their position boils down to "Too bad. Learn to live with it.". https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q562011

Comment: @SpeedFreak Thanks a lot. Very useful link. I guess the cleanest way around this is to load the graphic at runtime and so control explicitly what type of `TGraphic` is used.